# Source code for TCP/IP stack

Tags: internet, networking

Am looking for an open source code for the TCP/IP stack. An explanation along the lines of the stack would also help me in understanding the different modules and their interactions. I tried searching but there is very less information relating to just the TCP/IP stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can browse the entire Linux kernel at [LXR](http://lxr.linux.no). For example, [here's](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c) the implementation of TCP over IPv4. Be aware that a full, real-world TCP/IP stack is going to be *huge* and it's going to be difficult getting a feel from it just by studying source code.

There are many books available which give you more of an overview, such as [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201633469) and [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/020163354X). Follow the "related titles" link in Amazon for many more...

Answer (score 4):

Besides the obvious answer of current OSS kernels (Linux and BSD are the usual suspects), there are some other smaller and easier to read implementations.  A quick googling gave me these:

- [LwIP](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/lwip/)
- [µIP](http://www.sics.se/~adam/uip/index.php/Main_Page)

Comment: µIP is now at https://github.com/adamdunkels/uip